# Find a ball about a fixed point of an autonomous ODE such that all points within the ball eventually converge to the fixed point or leave the ball

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the autonomous ODE $x'=f(x)$ where $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ is a vector of polynomials. Let $x_0$ be a fixed point of the ODE ($f(x_0)=0$). Assume the jacobian of $f$ at $x_0$ is non singular and has both positive and negative eigenvalues (its a non degenerate saddle point). Because the ODE is approximately linear near the fixed point, I highly suspect the following holds:

Let $B_r(x_0)$  denote the ball of radius $r$ centred at $x_0$. Then the following holds:
There exists $r>0$ such that any solution starting in $B_r(x_0)$ either converges to $x_0$ or it will eventually leave $B_r(x_0)$, that is to say, there exists some time $T$ after which the solution leaves the ball.

This is true for any non degenerate saddle point of a linear system and any radius, however, in the non linear case, not all radii will work. I am interested in finding a method by which I can find such a radius for specific non linear ODEs of the form $x'=f(x)$ where $f$ is an n-dimensional vector of polynomials.

Additionally, if my claim that such a positive radius always exists in the specific case of polynomial $f$ is false, then I would like to see a counter example. Moreover, if I am correct, a proof would be nice, however I am mainly interested in the method for finding a radius.

Finally, I would like to mention that I am not asking for a method for finding the largest possible radius, I just want some positive radius.